# How to get dataframe name from list for newt use in forloop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export, pandas.excelwriter

can you please help me with this code ?

I tried to create function to loop through dataframes used in current file, listed in: list_of_dfs
The code gives me an error.

```
# dataframe names will not be always df1,df2 etc
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]})

test_filenames = ['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx']
list_of_dfs = ['df1','df2','df3']
folder = 'C:\\Users\\name'
file___name = 'test01.xlsx'

def save_multiple_dataframes_to_xlsx(df_list:list,list_of_files:list, output_folder, file_name:str):
    path = output_folder +'\\' + file_name
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    for data_frame in list_of_dfs:
        df_index = list_of_dfs.index(data_frame) # Get index of dataframe
        sheet_names = list_of_files[df_index] # Get sheet name by df index from list_of_file list 
        
        # Tried to convert string to variable name for specification of dataframe for export
        def convert_list_element_to_var_name(data_frame=data_frame):
            return print(data_frame)
        
        # Save specific dataframe to excel worksheet
        convert_list_element_to_var_name(data_frame).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_names,index=False)

# Run function to save dataframes
save_multiple_dataframes_to_xlsx(df_list=list_of_dfs, list_of_files=test_filenames, output_folder=folder, file_name=file___name)
```

Return error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function returns `None`, so `convert_list_element_to_var_name(data_frame)` is `None` and you can't apply the method `to_excel` to it.

Comment: `data_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_names,index=False)` i get error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`. Do you have any idea how I can Itransform list element to use the element as dataframe name ?

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are trying to do. Maybe you want `list_of_dfs = [df1,df2,df3]` instead of `list_of_dfs = ['df1','df2','df3']`?

Comment: You´re Correct. Final script should do: Read multiple files in folder > load each file to separate dataframe > transform and clean each dataframe > save each source file/dataframe to one file into separate worksheets named by source filename.  I would like to dynamicly generate list of dataframes (I get  `list_of_dfs = ['df1','df2','df3']`). But I need `list_of_dfs = [df1,df2,df3]` and use it for export `dataframe_name.to_excel` .  Maybe you know much better approach with the same output.